# Safari Elements Disappearing After jQuery Interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I'm having some strange issues in Safari on Mac desktop and on iOS on a site currently being built. It seems that when there are jQuery interactions with elements, the elements disappear. When I inspect the element, I can't see any properties that indicate why the element would be hidden. If I toggle one of the checkboxes on any of the CSS properties for the element, it reappears.

**Steps to Recreate**

1. In Safari, go to: http://bisqitstage.promotw.com/
2. Refresh the page using the refresh button (not by hitting return on the URL).
3. Click the darker area (intended checkbox) to the right of "I agree to the terms and conditions of the site.".

   - Here is where you should see a checkmark appear based on the jQuery event.
4. Right click the box area and choose "Inspect Element".
5. In the HTML inspector, within div.bisqit-checkbox click on div.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok.check.
6. Scroll down within the CSS inspector and toggle the checkbox next to any of the property options (for example, uncheck and then re-check width: 35px;).

   - The checkmark will now be displayed

**Expected**

After step 3, the checkmark should be displayed after step 3. When inspecting in step 6, if you chose "width" for instance, the property was already checked. Unchecking it and checking it again shouldn't change it's state - so why does it not display after step 3?

I'm having several issues similar to this within this site build. I've tried different jQuery versions as well as removing other components that might be interfering, but cannot seem to resolve the issue.

Browser Version: Safari 7.1 (although we've noticed it back to v6).

Comment: Your page has some sort of corruption issue in the the `<script>` tag that contains `var base_url = ...`.  You appear to have some sort of mix of javascript and HTML within the same tag.  If you're wondering where it is, look at the first script error reports in your page.

Comment: The same thing is happening to me, did you find a solution?